# jQuery.getJSON read data

Tags: jquery, getjson

Why is the code below not working? I can see in FireBug that the `data` variable contains the reply with the data I expect:

```
"[{"nextID":"STK000022"}]"
```

But when I try and access the value I get "undefined".

```
jQuery.post( get_data_url, FormData, function(data) {
    sessionStorage.ticket_id = data[0].nextID;      <--- UNDEFINED HERE
})
.done(function(data) {
    showPopupMsg(successClass, false, "New ticket successfully created!<br/>New ticket number: <strong>" + sessionStorage.ticket_id);
    // Reset form
    jQuery( '#PartnerNewTicketForm' ).reset();
})
.fail(function(jqxhr, textStatus, error ) {
    var sysError = textStatus + ", " + error;
    showPopupMsg(errorClass, logoutFlag, "The application has failed to create the new ticket. Error: " + sysError);    
})
.always(function(data) {
});
```

Comment: Did you try it without the `[0]` in `data[0].nextID`?

Comment: can you try data=jQuery.parseJSON(data); before the line sessionStorage.ticket_id = data[0].nextID;

Comment: firstly your data coming from firebird is in incorrect form, this must be like this '[{"nextID":"STK000022"}]' and if it is coming in this form then you should be able to use it the same way your are using, or try JSON.parse(data) and then use data[0].nextID

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the server is returning JSON, you need to tell jQuery about it, by giving a 4th argument to `$.post`:

```
jQuery.post( get_data_url, FormData, function(data) {
    sessionStorage.ticket_id = data[0].nextID;
}, 'json')
```

Specifying `json` as the `dataType` argument tells jQuery that it should parse the JSON into an object.

Comment: I didn't know that filling in arguments according to the documentation counts as a "trick".

Answer (score 2):

I think your server is returning string, instead of json object. So you should make it as object before use. Use `jQuery.parseJSON(` to make a string as object.

```
jQuery.post( get_data_url, FormData, function(data) {
    data=jQuery.parseJSON(data);
    sessionStorage.ticket_id = data[0].nextID;     
})
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/J24yN/225/)

Comment: This is corroborated by the fact that FireBug prints a string, not a JS object.

Comment: A JSON object _is_ a string. It's a string that contains the serialized version of an object.

Comment: @Barmar While that's totally correct, people often say "JSON object" when they mean "JS object".

Comment: @Scimonster I understand that clueless people posting questions do that, I expect better of the people posting answers.

Comment: @Barmar I have a doubt. How can we say that json object is a string since we are not enclosing it in double quotes?

Comment: There's no such thing as a "JSON object", there's just JSON: JavaScript Object Notation. It's a notation for representing a Javascript object in a string. JSON.stringify turns an object into JSON, JSON.parse turns JSON into an object.

Comment: @AnoopJoshi You seem to have a fundamental misunderstanding of what JSON is. According to JSON stands for JavaScript Object Notation - a data format. It is always a string. It can then be parsed into the language's object data.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you for the info. Now i got the point. I'll never say 'json object' again. :)